# Add class methods for custom acts_as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

I want to dynamically add class methods on a call of `acts_as` method. My file structure looks like this (taken from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html):

```
module ActsAsFoo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_foo(options = {})
      include ActsAsFoo::LocalInstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module LocalInstanceMethods
    def instance_method
      # This method works without any issue
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  acts_as_foo
end
```

I want to be able to declare class methods **only** when class calls `acts_as_foo`. Instance methods works with `LocalInstanceMethods`. The easiest way is to add in into module, but all my other classes have this method too. I already try to add a `define_method` into `acts_as` method, returns undefined method. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want to add class methods or instance methods to `Bar`? Your question says class methods, but the module is called `LocalInstanceMethods`

Comment: @Slicedpan I was not clear. I rewrite my question. I can add local instances without issue, but not class methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to create a second submodule and use `extend` instead of `include`

```
module ActsAsFoo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def acts_as_foo(options = {})
      extend ActsAsFoo::LocalClassMethods
    end
  end

  module LocalClassMethods
    def class_method
      # class method definition
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  acts_as_foo
end
```